# How can I unbend, straighten or flatten a bent rotor?

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake

Some possibilities, which I haven't tried:

- try to bend it back into shape with my hands while still mounted
- take off the rotor, sandwich it between a couple of wooden blocks, put some weight on it and leave it for a night

Comment: For emergency or "in a hurry" situations, inserting an allen key or screwdriver through one of the the cooling holes in the disk and GENTLY applying some force is a nice trick.

Comment: solution 2 doesn't work for minor bends because rotors are very elastic.

Answer (score 5):

Try a Park DT-2 rotor tool or something similar.I've used a large adjustable wrench with mixed results.Usually the larger the clearance between the pads and rotor the more forgiveing it will be to the rotor being a little off.I leave the wheel mounted,spin it to find the high spot .Then tighten the wrench on to the rotor and flex gently to straighten the rotor.

Comment: Cheers, just ordered one of these.

Comment: Also, If you had a park tool TS-2 truing stand, you could get a park tool DT-3 Rotor Truing Gauge to help measure how true your rotor is.